Flutter web create stream use yield alway throw Bad state: Stream has already been listened to
I want to read file from web choose by user as a stream, and send to http server, but it throw "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to".
then I write a simply test like below, but it still throw "Bad state: Stream has already been listened to".
And this test code is work find in Android. So is this a bug of flutter web?
Stream<List<int>> getChunkStream() async* {
    for(int i = 0; i < 100; i ++ ) {
      yield [1,2,3];
    }
  }

 void testReadChunk() async {
    Stream<List<int>> stream = getChunkStream();
    List<int> buffer = [];
    try{
      final list = await stream.toList();
      print("buffer1 $list");
      stream.listen((data){
        buffer.addAll(data);
      }).onDone((){
        print("buffer $buffer");
      });
    } on Exception catch(e) {
      print("e $e");
    }
 }


flutter doctor
Running flutter doctor...
Doctor summary (to see all details, run flutter doctor -v):
[✓] Flutter (Channel stable, 3.22.1, on macOS 13.5 22G74 darwin-arm64, locale zh-Hans-CN)
[✓] Android toolchain - develop for Android devices (Android SDK version 34.0.0)
[✓] Xcode - develop for iOS and macOS (Xcode 15.0.1)
[✓] Chrome - develop for the web
[✓] Android Studio (version 2023.2)
[✓] VS Code (version 1.88.1)
[✓] Connected device (4 available)
    ! Error: Browsing on the local area network for . Ensure the device is unlocked and attached with a cable or associated with the same local area network as this Mac.
      The device must be opted into Developer Mode to connect wirelessly. (code -27)
[✓] Network resources


